# Getting 404 not found in application deployed to Jboss 7.4.0

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, jboss7.x, jboss5.x

I am trying to upgrade Jboss 5.2 to Jboss 7.4.0 for my one of the application and I am able to deploy my application successfully as can be seen in the server logs..

```
23:31:23,113 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) WFLYCLINF0002: Started http-remoting-connector cache from ejb container
23:31:23,191 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 73) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/users' for server 'default-server'
23:31:23,279 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "users.war" (runtime-name : "users.war")
23:31:23,318 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
23:31:23,320 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: JBoss EAP 7.4.0.GA (WildFly Core 15.0.2.Final-redhat-00001) started in 8949ms - Started 429 of 648 services (372 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

But when I am hitting any api then its giving me 404 :

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>Not Found</body>

</html>
```

The API which I am hitting is /users/rs/healthcheck.form and this works fine in Jboss 5.2 but in Jboss 7.4.0 its giving below response in logs :

```
00:15:07,380 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (default task-1) Attempting to authenticate /users/rs/healthcheck.form
, authentication required: false
00:15:07,382 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (default task-1) Authentication outcome was NOT_ATTEMPTED with method io.undertow.security.impl.CachedAuthenticatedSessionMechanism@504ee2f9 for /users/rs/healthcheck.form%0A
00:15:07,382 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (default task-1) Authentication result was ATTEMPTED for /users/rs/healthcheck.form

00:15:07,396 INFO  [io.undertow.request.dump] (default task-1)
----------------------------REQUEST---------------------------
               URI=/users/rs/healthcheck.form%0A
 characterEncoding=null
     contentLength=-1
       contentType=null
            header=Accept=*/*
            header=Postman-Token=42523129-26bb-4823-ae14-1b7c474cc45f
            header=Connection=keep-alive
            header=Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate, br
            header=Client-Server-IP=10.10.7.233
            header=User-Agent=PostmanRuntime/7.32.3
            header=Host=localhost:8080
            locale=[]
            method=GET
          protocol=HTTP/1.1
       queryString=
        remoteAddr=/127.0.0.1:55511
        remoteHost=kubernetes.docker.internal
            scheme=http
              host=localhost:8080
        serverPort=8080
          isSecure=false
--------------------------RESPONSE--------------------------
     contentLength=68
       contentType=text/html;charset=UTF-8
            header=Connection=keep-alive
            header=Content-Type=text/html;charset=UTF-8
            header=Content-Length=68
            header=Date=Tue, 29 Aug 2023 18:45:07 GMT
            status=404

========================================================
```

Do I need to change anything in the configuration for undertow in Jboss 7.4.0 for this to work ?